# What are the `^let` annotations in Android Studio / IntelliJ?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-14

In a `let` block, I sometimes see `^let` annotations before my statements, and it's not clear to me what they mean or why they are there.

Is it to indicate that a value will be returned as the value of the `let` call?

Screenshot:

[image: code snippet with ^let annotations]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These do in fact show you that those values are going to be returned from the `let` expression. If you move to cursor to one of these hints and open intention actions (Alt + Enter), you get the option "Do not show *lambda return expression hints*", which I suppose is the name for this new feature.

[image: The intention action in the IDE]

This change was introduced in Kotlin 1.2.20, see *IntelliJ IDEA Plugin Improvements* in [this post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/01/kotlin-1-2-20-is-out/).

Comment: How does one undo this intention? The intention disappears when there's no hints shown any more, and I can't find anything in preferences.

Comment: ^ found it: Preferences → Editor → General → Appearance → Show parameter name hints Configure → Language: Kotlin → Show lambda return expression hints

Answer (score 4):

Your screenshot demonstrates two new IDE features that were introduced with [Kotlin Plugin 1.2.20](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.20/ChangeLog.md):

[KT 20533](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issueMobile/KT-20533) **Show "this" and "it" type hints in lambdas.**

[KT-20067](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issueMobile/KT-20067) **Return label hints**

Here’s the description of KT-20066 that’s  related to the question:

> Returns from lambdas can be confusing, especially when lambdas are nested or crossinline. It is often difficult to determine the lambda's return type and where a block is returning to, which may cause subtle compilation errors or runtime bugs. One solution is to always use explicit labeled returns and type signatures, however this can add extra noise to the source code. One suggestion for improving readability is to use IDE hinting (like in parameter hints), for lambda returns in Kotlin.