# What does ^map mean in Android Studio 4.0?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

The following code is from the project https://github.com/android/databinding-samples.git

What does ^map mean in Android Studio 4.0 ?  It seems that I can't delete it and I can't hide it.

**Code Image**

[image]

Comment: That's just the return statement of map function, meaning that this statement is the result of map function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the \`^let\` annotations in Android Studio / IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395318/what-are-the-let-annotations-in-android-studio-intellij)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Lambda return expression hints and you can hide them here in the settings:

[image]

Or via a quick action:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is actually pointing that it is going to be returned to the lambda passed in the `map` function.

By default the lambda name is same as the function you are calling (`map` in this case), and by default the lambda returns the last expression that is `when` in this case. So it will return it to the lambda. you can also explicitly specify that by `return@map Popularity.STAR` as well.

You can also change the name of the lambda if that bothers you,

```kotlin
Transformations.map(_likes) myLambdaName@ {
        when {
            it > 9 -> Popularity.STAR    // will show as `^myLambdaName`
            it > 4 -> return@myLambdaName Popularity.POPULAR  // explicitly specifying return statement
            else -> Popularity.NORMAL    // will show as `^myLambdaName`
        }
    }
```